# intellji "Maven Project" tool window does not show "Dependencies" node

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

[image]

I created a new project, enabled auto-import, add some dependencies in pom.xml
However,  unlike previous project, there is no "Dependencies" node displayed in left "Maven Project" tool window. And when i code, found dependencies have not been added

So could anyone help here?

Comment: Have you tried [Importing Maven dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_dependency) explicitly in Maven tool window?

Comment: Delete tag dependencyManagement (Dependency Management allows to consolidate and centralize the management of dependency versions WITHOUT adding dependencies)

Comment: @Andrey   Hi, I followed the instruction in your link,  it does not work.

Comment: @SergioGragera   you saved my day